# How to open a pop up in an activity and in that pop up radio buttons should be displayed how it is done in android?

Tags: java, android

I want to implement this code to dispaly in popup?
Here is my code...

```
package com.map.mapappn;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    protected static final CharSequence OK = null;
    Button click;
    private RadioGroup radioGroup;
    TextView tv;
    // //final CharSequence[] colors_vehicles = { "bus", "man", "bike", "train",
    // "car" };

    private RadioButton bus, bike, car, man, train;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        click = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        click.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                PopUp();

            }
        });
    }

    protected void PopUp() {

        final Dialog dialogue = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialogue.setTitle("MODE OF TRANSFER");
        dialogue.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio);

        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

                // find which radio button is selected

                if (checkedId == R.id.btnBike) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "choice: Bike",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else if (checkedId == R.id.btnBus) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "choice: Bus",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else if (checkedId == R.id.btnCar) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "choice: Car",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else if (checkedId == R.id.btnMan) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "choice: Man",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else if (checkedId == R.id.btnMan) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "choice: train",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else {
                }

            }

        });

        bus = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.btnBus);

        bike = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.btnBike);

        car = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.btnCar);

        man = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.btnMan);

        train = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.btnTrain);

        click.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

                // find which radioButton is checked by id

                if (selectedId == man.getId()) {

                    tv.setText("You chose 'MAN' option");

                } else if (selectedId == bike.getId()) {

                    tv.setText("You chose 'BIKE' option");

                } else if (selectedId == bus.getId()) {

                    tv.setText("You chose 'BUS' option");

                } else if (selectedId == car.getId()) {

                    tv.setText("You chose 'CAR' option");

                } else if (selectedId == train.getId()) {

                    tv.setText("You chose 'TRAIN' option");

                } else {
                }

            }

        });

        dialogue.show();
        dialogue.getWindow().setLayout(400, 550);``

    }
}
```

I want to open a pop up and in that  radio group should be displayed?So suggest me....Is it the correct code if not ....

How to open  a pop up in an activity  and in that pop up radio buttons should be displayed how it is done in android?

Comment: Are you facing errors?

Comment: u r wrong way your pop up gaeing error

Comment: can you try using spinner

Comment: do you facing any problem while using it??

Comment: Ya Ianm getting errror as Null pointer exception and setOncheckedChangeListener() but what type of error it is???